# AWS Identity Center - Can't see other OUs

Tags: amazon-web-services

I enabled Control Tower and Identity Center in AWS on my root account, and during the setup process, AWS created an audit and archive account in a new OU - the security OU. Now, when I create a new user in Identity Center and assign it a permission set, when I sign in, I can't see the other OU's I created (dev, prod and security). The user is assigned the permission set and is assigned to the default root account in Organisations.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you assigned the users or groups to the account? What I usually do is create a group in IAM Identity Center -> Groups, add users to the group and then navigate to IAM Identity Center -> Multi Account Permissions -> AWS Accounts, select the accounts I want to assign a group to and then click the button "Assign users or groups" and then complete the steps.

Comment: This should be a comment if it's asking a question from OP

Comment: oh, I think I figured out my issue - so I created the group and tried to assign it to the OU's under Root but they are all greyed out, but the two groups I created in Control Tower are not greyed out. The two groups are Log-Archive and Audit and they sit under the Security OU.

So, my question now is: how do I create a subgroup in my OUs?

Comment: Ignore the above. I'm in AWS Accounts - Organisation and I can now expand my OUs - dev, prod and security. There is a management account, which is the default account I believe. I created a personal account for myself and added myself as a member to the default management account. 

Is it best practice to move said management account to Root, so anyone that logs in can view all of the OUs within Root?

I hope I explained it well